# List all keys from a Riak KV using the Java client

Tags: riak

How to List all Keys from a Riak KV Bucket?

I am a getting a Response using the rest API,

**http://localhost:8098/buckets/bucket_name/keys?keys=true**

but not with the Java client.

Answer (score 1):

First off I would caution that listing keys is an expensive operation and should not be done on a production cluster. That said please check out the Java client documentation (the latest version can be found here: http://basho.github.io/riak-java-client/2.1.0/). Under com.basho.riak.client.api.commands.kv you will find the section on List Keys which has the following example:

```
Namespace ns = new Namespace("my_type", "my_bucket");
ListKeys lk = new ListKeys.Builder(ns).build();
ListKeys.Response response = client.execute(lk);
for (Location l : response)
{
     System.out.println(l.getKeyAsString());
}
```

There is also an example there that demonstrates how to stream the results back to the client.